# Deploying Angular application to a Preview channel on Firebase

Tags: firebase, angularfire2, firebase-hosting

I have deployed an Angular project to firebase hosting, which has worked fine, but I am now trying to deploy a test channel to demonstrate some new features to colleagues and team members.  I've been unable to get it working properly though:

Here is my setup:

I have run `firebase hosting:channel:create test-author`.
That runs normally and returned a success message and url

But when I try to deploy the test version of my site with
`firebase hosting:channel:deploy test-author`

This returns an error: `Unable to parse JSON: SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0` which I think is because the command returned some sort of HTML instead of the expected JSON.  Running it with `--debug` yields the errors below:  (some details redacted).  If I look on the firebase hosting console, I can see that the preview channel test author was created, but attempt to visit the site gives `Site Not Found Error`.

Not surprising because it looks like the site was never actually deployed.  (Should be noted that the deploy to the default site works fine and is running normally.  This is for testing new features.).

I thought this might have something to do with firebase.json, so I added this section to the 'hosting key', but get the same result.  (Current contents of Firebase.json beneath the error.

Suggestions on how to get this working properly?

Thanks.

```
[2023-04-09T23:36:34.335Z] > command requires scopes: ["email","openid","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloudplatformprojects.readonly","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/firebase","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform"]
[2023-04-09T23:36:34.335Z] > authorizing via signed-in user (grapXXXXXXXXail.com)
[2023-04-09T23:36:34.335Z] [iam] checking project bkXXXXXcf for permissions ["firebase.projects.get","firebasehosting.sites.update"]
[2023-04-09T23:36:34.336Z] >>> [apiv2][query] POST https://cloudresourcemanager.googleapis.com/v1/projects/bkopy-63ecf:testIamPermissions [none]
[2023-04-09T23:36:34.336Z] >>> [apiv2][(partial)header] POST https://cloudresourcemanager.googleapis.com/v1/projects/bkopy-63ecf:testIamPermissions x-goog-quota-user=projects/bkopy-63ecf
[2023-04-09T23:36:34.336Z] >>> [apiv2][body] POST https://cloudresourcemanager.googleapis.com/v1/projects/bkopy-63ecf:testIamPermissions {"permissions":["firebase.projects.get","firebasehosting.sites.update"]}
[2023-04-09T23:36:34.546Z] <<< [apiv2][status] POST https://cloudresourcemanager.googleapis.com/v1/projects/bkopy-63ecf:testIamPermissions 200
[2023-04-09T23:36:34.546Z] <<< [apiv2][body] POST https://cloudresourcemanager.googleapis.com/v1/projects/bkopy-63ecf:testIamPermissions {"permissions":["firebase.projects.get","firebasehosting.sites.update"]}
[2023-04-09T23:36:34.547Z] >>> [apiv2][query] GET https://firebase.googleapis.com/v1beta1/projects/bkopy-63ecf [none]
[2023-04-09T23:36:34.805Z] <<< [apiv2][status] GET https://firebase.googleapis.com/v1beta1/projects/bkopy-63ecf 200
[2023-04-09T23:36:34.806Z] <<< [apiv2][body] GET https://firebase.googleapis.com/v1beta1/projects/bkopy-63ecf {"projectId":"bkopy-63ecf","projectNumber":"97XXXXXXX11","displayName":"bkopy","name":"projects/bkopy-63ecf","resources":{"hostingSite":"bkopy-63ecf","realtimeDatabaseInstance":"bkopy-63ecf-default-rtdb","storageBucket":"bkopy-63ecf.appspot.com","locationId":"us-central"},"state":"ACTIVE","etag":"1_XXXXXXXX"}
[2023-04-09T23:36:34.807Z] >>> [apiv2][query] GET https://firebasehosting.googleapis.com/v1beta1/projects/bkopy-63ecf/sites/https://bkopy-63ecf.web.app/channels/test-author [none]
[2023-04-09T23:36:34.808Z] >>> [apiv2][query] GET https://firebasehosting.googleapis.com/v1beta1/projects/bkopy-63ecf/sites/test-author/channels/test-author [none]
[2023-04-09T23:36:35.248Z] <<< [apiv2][status] GET https://firebasehosting.googleapis.com/v1beta1/projects/bkopy-63ecf/sites/https://bkopy-63ecf.web.app/channels/test-author 404
[2023-04-09T23:36:35.249Z] <<< [apiv2][body] GET https://firebasehosting.googleapis.com/v1beta1/projects/bkopy-63ecf/sites/https://bkopy-63ecf.web.app/channels/test-author "<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html lang=en>\n  <meta charset=utf-8>\n  <meta name=viewport content=\"initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width\">\n  <title>Error 404 (Not Found)!!1</title>\n  <style>\n    *{margin:0;padding:0}html,code{font:15px/22px arial,sans-serif}html{background:#fff;color:#222;padding:15px}body{margin:7% auto 0;max-width:390px;min-height:180px;padding:30px 0 15px}* > body{background:url(//www.google.com/images/errors/robot.png) 100% 5px no-repeat;padding-right:205px}p{margin:11px 0 22px;overflow:hidden}ins{color:#777;text-decoration:none}a img{border:0}@media screen and (max-width:772px){body{background:none;margin-top:0;max-width:none;padding-right:0}}#logo{background:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) no-repeat;margin-left:-5px}@media only screen and (min-resolution:192dpi){#logo{background:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) no-repeat 0% 0%/100% 100%;-moz-border-image:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) 0}}@media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:2){#logo{background:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) no-repeat;-webkit-background-size:100% 100%}}#logo{display:inline-block;height:54px;width:150px}\n  </style>\n  <a href=//www.google.com/><span id=logo aria-label=Google></span></a>\n  <p><b>404.</b> <ins>That’s an error.</ins>\n  <p>The requested URL <code>/v1beta1/projects/bkopy-63ecf/sites/https://bkopy-63ecf.web.app/channels/test-author</code> was not found on this server.  <ins>That’s all we know.</ins>\n"
[2023-04-09T23:36:35.289Z] <<< [apiv2][status] GET https://firebasehosting.googleapis.com/v1beta1/projects/bkopy-63ecf/sites/test-author/channels/test-author 404
[2023-04-09T23:36:35.289Z] <<< [apiv2][body] GET https://firebasehosting.googleapis.com/v1beta1/projects/bkopy-63ecf/sites/test-author/channels/test-author {"error":{"code":404,"message":"Requested entity was not found.","status":"NOT_FOUND"}}
[2023-04-09T23:36:35.290Z] >>> [apiv2][query] POST https://firebasehosting.googleapis.com/v1beta1/projects/bkopy-63ecf/sites/test-author/channels?channelId=test-author [none]
[2023-04-09T23:36:35.291Z] >>> [apiv2][body] POST https://firebasehosting.googleapis.com/v1beta1/projects/bkopy-63ecf/sites/test-author/channels?channelId=test-author {"ttl":"604800s"}

Error: Unable to parse JSON: SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
```

```
{
  "hosting": [
    {
      "target": "public",
      "public": "dist/bkopyexplorer",
      "rewrites": [
        {
          "source": "**",
          "destination": "/index.html"
        }
      ],
      "ignore": [
        "firebase.json",
        "**/.*",
        "**/node_modules/**"
      ]
    },
    {
      "target": "test-author",
      "public": "dist/bkopyexplorer",
      "ignore": [
        "firebase.json",
        "**/.*",
        "**/node_modules/**"
      ],
      "rewrites": [
        {
          "source": "**",
          "destination": "/index.html"
        }
      ]
    }

  ]
}
```